# Create Blank Page with One Web Part Zone

Tags: master-page, page-layout, custom-masterpage, custom, sitepages

I need a web page that only has one web part zone. No ribbon. No header. No footer. I created a new master page in an attempt to set the foundation for a blank page. Then i created a new page and pointed it to the "masterpagefile" i just created. For some reason, when i try to view the page - it isn't working and resolves in an "Unexpected error has occurred" message. I'm new to master pages and page layouts. Did i leave out an important piece of code?

Here's the **Master Page Code**:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register tagprefix="SharePoint" namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<html dir="ltr">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint"/>
<meta name="progid" content="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/>
<SharePoint:RobotsMetaTag runat="server"></SharePoint:RobotsMetaTag>
<title id="onetidTitle"><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server"/></title>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</form>
</body>
```

Here's the **Custom Page Code**:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" masterpagefile="../_catalogs/masterpage/blank_2018.master" title="blank-kiz" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" meta:webpartpageexpansion="full" inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePointWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="PublishingWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="PublishingNavigation" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<WebPartPages:SPProxyWebPartManager runat="server" id="spproxywebpartmanager"></WebPartPages:SPProxyWebPartManager>
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone id="g_GDC287938C89408597431DCDDB87CC80" runat="server" title="Zone 1"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate>
</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
</asp:Content>
```

How can i make these work together?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I made sure I put the Web Part Manager code on the .aspx page but I didn't realize I had to also put that statement on the master page. Once i added this statement to the master page, the page resolved correctly.

```
<WebPartPages:SPWebPartManager id="m" runat="Server"/>
```